# Dot needs to stop at right edge

Tags: java, arrays, loops, object, int

This program has a 20-sided die and rolls the die before moving the 7 dot objects which then moves the dots the dice rolls number of pixels in the horizontal direction. I am trying to get the dot race to stop when the right edge of the top dot (dot[0]) touches the window. Everything works fine but the race stops when the left edge of the top dot reaches the window instead of the right edge. I believe the error is in the while condition where i put /* the right edge of the top dot */ I am also having trouble with using a function to determine the maximum x-coordinate of any Dot in an array.  (If the maximum crosses the finish line, the race is over.) The function I placed is: public static int leadingXCoordinate( Dot[] dotList )

```
public class FlyMe {

    private final static int GWINDOW_HEIGHT = 800;
    private final static int GWINDOW_WIDTH = 450;

    private static JFrame mainFrame;
    private static GCanvas dotCourse;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    createWindows();

    Dot [] dots = new Dot [7];
    for (int i = 0; i < dots.length; i++){
    dots[i] = new Dot(10, 114*i, 70, FlyMe.getRandomColor(), dotCourse);
    }
    Dice die = new Dice(20);
    while (/* the right edge of the top dot */ dots[0].getX() < GWINDOW_WIDTH)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dots.length; i++)
        {
            int hstep = die.roll();
            dots[i].moveDot(dots[i].getX() + hstep, dots[i].getY());
            Thread.sleep(50);
        }
    }

    // Creates JFrame window and graphics canvas for animation
    public static Color getRandomColor() {
        Random r = new Random();
        return new Color(r.nextInt(255), r.nextInt(255), r.nextInt(255));
    }

    /**
     * Determine the x-coordinate of the right-most Dot.
     *
     * @param dotList
     *            an array of the balloons being scanned
     * @return the maximum x-coordinate of any baloon in the arrays
     */
    // public static int leadingXCoordinate( Dot[] dotList ) {
    //
    // }
    private static void createWindows() {
        mainFrame = new JFrame("Dot Races");
        mainFrame.setSize(GWINDOW_WIDTH, GWINDOW_HEIGHT);
        mainFrame.setLocation(0, 0);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        dotCourse = new GCanvas(); // drawing space
        dotCourse.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(GWINDOW_WIDTH, GWINDOW_HEIGHT));
        dotCourse.setLocation(0, 0);
        dotCourse.setBackground(Color.white);

        mainFrame.add(dotCourse);
        mainFrame.pack();
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);

    }// CreateWindows

}// FlyMe
```

Comment: The dot's getx will return the left most x-coordinate associated with the dot, because the (0,0) origin is actually at the top left. For that while condition you should make it the dot's getx + the size of the dot to move the x coordinate spot to the right edge, which is the edge you want.

Comment: So it would be something like `while (dots[0].getX() + dots[0].size() < GWINDOW_WIDTH)` I am not sure if the size() function is valid, but whatever the dot's size is is what you would put there.

Comment: yeah the size() function unfortunately is not valid. The size of the dot is 10 but when I try (dots[0].getX() + 10 < GWINDOW_WIDTH) it still does not work

Comment: So after making it check for the right edge, it still stops only when the left edge is met?

Comment: great it worked thanks!